# High Disk I/O from sql server or is High disk I/O slowing sql server?

Tags: sql-server, perfmon

I've been arguing with a DBA and a couple hardware guys about performance issues on our SQL server.  Normally everything is fine, however over the past few weeks we have been having huge lag spikes in sql server.  Its clear that SQL Server is waiting on disk I/O.  But I keep getting told that it is beacuse SQL Server is asking for abnormally high I/O.  Which isn't the case.  I can see from what is running that there is nothing out of the normal, and all the DBA cares to look at is what is causing the blocking and so on, which is useless.  For instance the major thing we see backing up is operation on the ASPState database, which we are using to manage the ASP Session State on the web servers.  These operations are normally never seen on Sp_who2 active results because they occur so quickly.  The database is in simple recovery mode and logging is miminal.  However during these lag spikes we can see alot select and update operations on the database being blocked or waiting.   I'm sure what is going on is that someone or some job is running something that is causing heavey disk usage on the raid arrays used for that databases log and data files.  The problem is proving it, since no one wants to admit they are doing something that is killing our website.

My question is what performance counters or whatever can I log that will help show that SQL server is waiting on I/O, but not because its asking for more than normaly, instead beacuse the disk is to busy to respond to the requests from sql server as quickly as it normally would?

Comment: What wait state are you actually seeing, Network I/O? i.e., are you using a SAN?

Comment: Check to see if you have any queries that are dominating resource usage on the DB server.  If there are, try tuning those.  If you don't have any badly behaving queries, then high PAGEIOLATCH waits will typically indicate your system is I/O bound.  Also, as @EricHiggins says, SANs are often slow and cause performance issues with databases.

Comment: Its a NETAPP array connected to the sql server with Qlogic fiber HBA's.

Comment: I know this is a relatively old question, and this won't directly fix your issue... but we switched to aspnet_state.exe for session state and saw a great load off of our SQL Server. It's not well documented but pretty easy to setup.

Comment: So what did you/the DBA end up doing and what was the problem?

Answer (score 20):

Have a look at the following perfmon counters:

- [SQL Server, Buffer Manager Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189628%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):
  `Page lookups/sec`
  `Page reads/sec`
  `Readahead pages/sec`
- [SQL Server, Access Methods Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177426%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
  `Full Scans/sec`
  `Range Scans/sec`
  `Skipped Ghosted Records/sec`
- [SQL Server, Wait Statistics Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190732%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
  `Page IO latch waits`

SQL Server driving a high number of IO requests would be corroborated with a high number scans, increase in page lookups and page reads and high page IO latch waits. Is worth trying a look at [`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx) for entries with high physical reads counts. They could quickly pinpoint the culprit.

In general approaching the problem as a performance troubleshooting problem, following a methodlogy like [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) is the right approach. You DBA seems to be doing the right thing so you should listen to him.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the DBA he is one of the best DBA's I've worked with.  And he's given me a list of high blocking stored procedures.  But as I mentioned one of the procs that is causing a lot of blocking is "TempUpdateStateItemLong"  which is a proc used by hte SQL Session state store.  Its a MS proc, and it only updates a single table by the sessionID which is the indexed primary key on the table.  Also at most this table has 2000-3000 records, so updates really should take no time at all.

Comment: This is a good place to start.  We are still running SQL Server 2000, we are in the process of upgrading but that won't happen for a few more months, so I don't have the PAge IO Latch waits counter to look at.  Thanks again.

Comment: Note that blocking per-se does not imply high IO. It could be lock contention, and that would affect the table no matter the size, specially if optimizer chooses a table scan based plan.

Comment: And also check the [Process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780836%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for `IO Data Bytes/sec` and see if some other process is trashing the disk.

Answer (score 13):

To start use Glenn Berry's [Diagnostic queries](https://glennsqlperformance.com/category/sql-server/sql-server-diagnostic-information-queries/) and Adam Machanic's [SP_Whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com) to find out whats really happening.

First see which database files have the most IO bottleneck by running this query(Query by  Glenn Berry)

```
SELECT  DB_NAME(fs.database_id) AS [Database Name] ,
        mf.physical_name ,
        io_stall_read_ms ,
        num_of_reads ,
        CAST(io_stall_read_ms / ( 1.0 + num_of_reads ) AS NUMERIC(10, 1)) AS [avg_read_stall_ms] ,
        io_stall_write_ms ,
        num_of_writes ,
        CAST(io_stall_write_ms / ( 1.0 + num_of_writes ) AS NUMERIC(10, 1)) AS [avg_write_stall_ms] ,
        io_stall_read_ms + io_stall_write_ms AS [io_stalls] ,
        num_of_reads + num_of_writes AS [total_io] ,
        CAST(( io_stall_read_ms + io_stall_write_ms ) / ( 1.0 + num_of_reads
                                                          + num_of_writes ) AS NUMERIC(10,
                                                              1)) AS [avg_io_stall_ms]
FROM    sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(NULL, NULL) AS fs
        INNER JOIN sys.master_files AS mf WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON fs.database_id = mf.database_id
                                                             AND fs.[file_id] = mf.[file_id]
ORDER BY avg_io_stall_ms DESC
OPTION  ( RECOMPILE );
```

Then run this query to see the top ten events your server is waiting on(query by [Jonathan Kehayias](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/)). You will also find similar query from Glenn Berry diagnostic queries.

```
SELECT TOP 10
        wait_type ,
        max_wait_time_ms wait_time_ms ,
        signal_wait_time_ms ,
        wait_time_ms - signal_wait_time_ms AS resource_wait_time_ms ,
        100.0 * wait_time_ms / SUM(wait_time_ms) OVER ( ) AS percent_total_waits ,
        100.0 * signal_wait_time_ms / SUM(signal_wait_time_ms) OVER ( ) AS percent_total_signal_waits ,
        100.0 * ( wait_time_ms - signal_wait_time_ms )
        / SUM(wait_time_ms) OVER ( ) AS percent_total_resource_waits
FROM    sys.dm_os_wait_stats
WHERE   wait_time_ms > 0 -- remove zero wait_time
        AND wait_type NOT IN -- filter out additional irrelevant waits
( 'SLEEP_TASK', 'BROKER_TASK_STOP', 'BROKER_TO_FLUSH', 'SQLTRACE_BUFFER_FLUSH',
  'CLR_AUTO_EVENT', 'CLR_MANUAL_EVENT', 'LAZYWRITER_SLEEP', 'SLEEP_SYSTEMTASK',
  'SLEEP_BPOOL_FLUSH', 'BROKER_EVENTHANDLER', 'XE_DISPATCHER_WAIT',
  'FT_IFTSHC_MUTEX', 'CHECKPOINT_QUEUE', 'FT_IFTS_SCHEDULER_IDLE_WAIT',
  'BROKER_TRANSMITTER', 'FT_IFTSHC_MUTEX', 'KSOURCE_WAKEUP',
  'LAZYWRITER_SLEEP', 'LOGMGR_QUEUE', 'ONDEMAND_TASK_QUEUE',
  'REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH', 'XE_TIMER_EVENT', 'BAD_PAGE_PROCESS',
  'DBMIRROR_EVENTS_QUEUE', 'BROKER_RECEIVE_WAITFOR',
  'PREEMPTIVE_OS_GETPROCADDRESS', 'PREEMPTIVE_OS_AUTHENTICATIONOPS', 'WAITFOR',
  'DISPATCHER_QUEUE_SEMAPHORE', 'XE_DISPATCHER_JOIN', 'RESOURCE_QUEUE' )
ORDER BY wait_time_ms DESC
```

Once you have this information at hand it would be much easier to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: I just used the final script in this list - its kick ass.

Answer (score 1):

"The problem is proving it", rightly said. Take a look at [SQL Server: Minimize Disk I/O](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj643251.aspx)

It is talking about following DMV

```
sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats
sys.dm_io_pending_io_requests
```

**References:**

1. [How to examine IO subsystem latencies from within SQL Server](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/how-to-examine-io-subsystem-latencies-from-within-sql-server/)
2. [Glenn Berry's SQL Server Performance - sys.dm_io_pending_io_requests](https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2010/04/27/a-dmv-a-day-%E2%80%93-day-28/)