# Disk I/O Activity

Tags: sql-server, performance

Resource Monitor on our SQL Server DB server shows very high fluctuating disk activity that I cannot understand.
I then check Activity Monitor and the Database I/O looks ok.

Any ideas why I am seeing such a difference?
Thanks

[image: Resource Monitor]

[image: Activity Monitor]

Answer (score 4):

If I read your graph correctly, your resource monitor shows the Disk I/O peaking at around 10MB/sec. That is not much and would correspond to the I/O graph from the activity monitor.

So, in my opinion, both images show the same data, only on a different scale.

Answer (score -1):

It can be due to many reasons like: some process/procedure, large data chunk fetch  ..etc. So just to answer the part - "Any ideas why I am seeing such a difference?" 
I think these will give you some insight:

http://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/sql-server-finding-the-source-of-excessive-io/

[High Disk I/O from sql server or is High disk I/O slowing sql server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16492/high-disk-i-o-from-sql-server-or-is-high-disk-i-o-slowing-sql-server)

http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/your-physical-disk-io-affecting-sql-server-performance

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199524/sql-server-high-cpu-and-i-o-activity-database-tuning